# when the c++ program stack size used is determined?

Tags: c++, c, stack

I know the maximum stack size usually is fixed on link (maybe on windows is that).

But I don't know when the program stack size ( not maximum stack size just used size) used is be fixed to OS. compile ? linked ? execute ?

like this:

```
int main(){ int a[10]; return 0;}
```

the program just use 10 * sizeof(int) stack. so, is the stack size  fixed?

above all. if the heap size is changed when malloc or free?

Comment: It's allocated by the OS on execution of a process.

Comment: FWIW, stack _size_ is not fixed, it expands at runtime as necessary, but stack _limit_ is fixed.

Comment: If your program only uses 40 bytes of stack (plus a little more for the run-time system) and the OS by default allocates an 8MB stack for the process (like Linux does), you still have almost 8MB stack left over.

Comment: This question is extremely unclear IMO. Consider placing each of those question marks in an appropriate place, i.e., at the end of a well-formed and readable question. For example, "so" is not a question, and neither is "if the size if fixed".

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just was be asked the problem when a company interview.

Comment: The stack size used by a program grows and shrinks as function calls are made and functions return after execution. I think you want to know whether the stack size used by a function is fixed at compile time, link time, or execution time.

Comment: Well... "so, if the size is fixed" is not a question either!!!

Comment: Thank you everyone. @barakmanos I have fixed the problem, I am sorry about the error, you are a considerate man. @R Sahu Yes! You understand me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Stack size is not explicitly provided to OS, when program is loaded. Instead, OS uses mechanism of [page faults](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) (if it is supported by MMU).

If you try to access memory which was not granted by operating system yet, MMU generates a page fault which is handled by OS. OS checks address of page fault and either expands stack by creating new memory page or if you have exhausted stack limits, handles it as *stack overflow*.

Consider following program running on x86 and Linux:

```
void foo(void) {
    volatile int a = 10;
    foo();
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

It faults because of infinite recursion and stack overflow. It actually requires infinite stack to be completed. When program is loaded, OS allocates initial stack and writes it to `%rsp` (stack pointer). Let's look at `foo()` disassembly:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp         <--- Save stackpointer to %rbp
sub    $0x10,%rsp        <--- Advance stack pointer by 16 bytes
movl   $0xa,-0x4(%rbp)   <--- Write memory at %rbp
callq  0x400500 <foo>
leaveq 
retq
```

After at most 4096 / 16 = 256 calls of `foo()`, you will break page boundary by writing a memory at address `X + 4096` where X is initial `%rsp` value. Then page fault will be generated, and OS provide new memory page for stack, allowing program to utilize it.

After about 500k of `foo()` calls (default Linux ulimit for stack), OS will detect that application utilizes too many stack pages and send SIGSEGV to it.

Answer (score 0):

In an answer to a question I provided the following information:

The BSS/DATA segment contains all the global variables, initialized to a specific value or to zero by default. This segment is part of the executable image. At load time, the heap segment is added to this; however, it is not a "segment" but just the amount of extra data to be allocated as an extension of the loaded BSS/DATA segment. In the same way the stack "segment" is not a true segment but is added to the BSS+heap segment. The stack grows down whereas the heap grows up. If these overlap (more heap used and stack still growing) an "out of memory" error occurrs (heap) or "stack overflow" (stack) - this may be detected with the use of segment registers (Intel) to trigger a hardware generated exception or by using software checks.

This is the traditional way of laying out the segments. Think of older Intel chips where all progeram data must be in 64KB. With more modern chips the same layout is often used where address space of 32MB is used in this layout but only actual physical memory required is used. The stack can thus be pretty big.